# Обновление всех фрагментов во viewpager из одного фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-fragment

Есть ли возможность из фрагмента находящимся во viewpager сделать вызов обновления все других фрагментов находящихся во viewpager

Comment: да, это можно сделать

Comment: Можете объяснить алгоритм

Comment: один из вариантов это добавления интерфейса во фрагменты и их последующий вызов.

Comment: А может через механизм broadcast?

Comment: Точнее через event bus

Comment: Регестрировать событие и при определенных условиях и реагировать на него

Comment: Со всех фрагментов во viewpager, которые на него подписаны

Comment: Реакция и последствия зависит только от вашей конечной цели. У вас вопрос слишком абстрактный, на него много вариантов реализации. И она (реализация) зависит только от ваших потребностей.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18088509/2667883 вот один из примеров

Answer (score 1):

Заюзал EventBus схему так удобнее